# Histogram ggplot : Show count label for each bin for each category

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'll use the diamond data set in ggplot to illustrate my point , I want to draw a histogram for price , but I want to show the count for each bin for each cut
this is my code

```
ggplot(aes(x = price ) , data = diamonds_df) + 
geom_histogram(aes(fill = cut , binwidth = 1500)) +
stat_bin(binwidth= 1500, geom="text", aes(label=..count..) , 
vjust = -1) + 
scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0 , max(stores_1_5$Weekly_Sales) , 1500 ) 
, labels = comma)
```

here is my current plot

[image]

but as you see the number shows the count for all cuts at each bin , I want to display the count for each cut on each bin .

also a bonus point if if I would be able to configure Y axis instead of displaying numbers at step of 5000 to something else I can configure manually

Comment: So you want to squeeze five numbers into every bin? Yeah, that will look pretty...

Comment: Yeah , totally right :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

#### Update for `ggplot2` 2.x

You can now center labels within stacked bars without pre-summarizing the data using `position=position_stack(vjust=0.5)`. For example:

```
ggplot(aes(x = price ) , data = diamonds) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(fill=cut), binwidth=1500, colour="grey20", lwd=0.2) +
  stat_bin(binwidth=1500, geom="text", colour="white", size=3.5,
           aes(label=..count.., group=cut), position=position_stack(vjust=0.5)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,max(diamonds$price), 1500))
```

#### Original Answer

You can get the counts for each value of `cut` by adding `cut` as a `group` aesthetic to `stat_bin`. I also moved `binwidth` outside of `aes`, which was causing `binwidth` to be ignored in your original code:

```
ggplot(aes(x = price ), data = diamonds) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(fill = cut ), binwidth=1500, colour="grey20", lwd=0.2) +
  stat_bin(binwidth=1500, geom="text", colour="white", size=3.5,
           aes(label=..count.., group=cut, y=0.8*(..count..))) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,max(diamonds$price), 1500))
```

[image]

One issue with the code above is that I'd like the labels to be vertically centered within each bar section, but I'm not sure how to do that within `stat_bin`, or if it's even possible. Multiplying by 0.8 (or whatever) moves each label by a different relative amount. So, to get the labels centered, I created a separate data frame for the labels in the code below:

```
# Create text labels
dat = diamonds %>% 
  group_by(cut, 
           price=cut(price, seq(0,max(diamonds$price)+1500,1500),
                     labels=seq(0,max(diamonds$price),1500), right=FALSE)) %>%
  summarise(count=n()) %>%
  group_by(price) %>%
  mutate(ypos = cumsum(count) - 0.5*count) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(price = as.numeric(as.character(price)) + 750)

ggplot(aes(x = price ) , data = diamonds) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(fill = cut ), binwidth=1500, colour="grey20", lwd=0.2) +
  geom_text(data=dat, aes(label=count, y=ypos), colour="white", size=3.5)
```

[image]

To configure the breaks on the y axis, just add `scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,20000,2000))` or whatever breaks you'd like.

Comment: of note, latest ggplot2 syntax (March 2023) would rather use `y = after_stat(count)` instead of `y = ..count..`

Answer (score -1):

Now with GGPLOT 2.2.0 position_stack options makes it easier

```
library(ggplot2)
s <- ggplot(mpg, aes(manufacturer, fill = class))
s + geom_bar(position = "stack") +  
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, vjust=1)) + 
    geom_text(stat='count', aes(label=..count..), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5),size=4)
```