# Showing X axis value label on top of the histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2

I searched for this but I only came with this similar question but labelling the count values in stacked histogram. What I want to do is that label just one `price` value on top of each histogram bar.

using the similar [histogram-ggplot-show-count-label-for-each-bin-for-each-category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30057765/histogram-ggplot-show-count-label-for-each-bin-for-each-category)

```
  ggplot(aes(x = price ), data = diamonds) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(fill = cut ), binwidth=1500, colour="grey20", lwd=0.2) +
  stat_bin(binwidth=1500, geom="text", colour="white", size=3.5,
           aes(label=..count.., group=cut, y=0.8*(..count..))) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,max(diamonds$price), 1500))
```

[image]

When I change `label=..count..` to `..price..` I get

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'price' not found

How I can we put `price` value on top of each histogram?

thanks in advance!

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10327267/annotation-above-bars) thread seems to have your answer.  Re: your error, `..count..` is a specific built-in `stat` variable that calls something similar to a `sum`

Comment: How will you decide which singular price value to show for the bin? The bins contain a range of prices.

Comment: @MrFlick That's a good point. Something like in the middle value is fine!

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of cobbled together. I don't know how to redefine something like the `..count..` special variable for a function like mean or median. Instead, I calculated the mean of price within each bin and then `annotate`-d. I chose to not put the mean price on top of the bars, since that would suggest incorrectly to the reader that these were counts, but they're not.

```
library(plyr)
mean.cut <- ddply(diamonds, .(cut(price,seq(0,max(diamonds$price), 1500))), 
                              summarize, v=mean(price))

ggplot(diamonds) +geom_histogram(aes(x=price,fill = cut ), binwidth=1500, 
                                 colour="grey20", lwd=0.2) +  
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,max(diamonds$price), 1500))+
  annotate("text", x=seq(0,max(diamonds$price), 1500),  y=mean.cut$v,
                  label=round(mean.cut$v,0))
```

[image]

I played around with formatting of hte price value and liked this code for labels of the various options I tried:

```
label=sprintf(" $%-5s", round(mean.cut$v,-1) )
```